# Convert foreach to linq expression with select

Tags: c#, linq

I have expression:

```
  var newValues = MetarDecoder.Decode(telegram)
                .OfType<MeteoParameter<decimal>>()
                .Select(parameter => MeteoParameterFactory
                .Create(parameter.ParameterId, parameter.DateTime.ToLocalTime(), parameter.Status, parameter.Value))                            
                .ToList();
```

`MeteoParameterFactory` cannot be changed for some reasons, just take it as it is.

`MeteoParameter` also have `string Info` property.

I need to copy `Info` from old `parameter` to `MeteoParameterFactory.Create()` result.

Without LINQ it looks like:

```
 var val = MetarDecoder.Decode(telegram).OfType<MeteoParameter<decimal>>().ToList();

                        foreach (var param in val)
                        {
                            var parameter = MeteoParameterFactory.Create(param.ParameterId, param.DateTime.ToLocalTime(), param.Status, param.Value);
                            parameter.Info = param.Info;
                            newValues.Add(parameter);
                        }
```

So, is there any way to add this part in LINQ expression shown below?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: .ForEach(param => ...) or ..Select(parameter => {...}) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Select` you can create an *anonymous function* that returns the `parameter` created inside of it.

```
var newValues = MetarDecoder.Decode(telegram)
            .OfType<MeteoParameter<decimal>>()
            .Select(param => { 
                   var parameter = MeteoParameterFactory.Create(param.ParameterId, param.DateTime.ToLocalTime(), param.Status, param.Value);
                   parameter.Info = param.Info;
                   return parameter;
             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = MetarDecoder
            .Decode(telegram)
            .OfType<MeteoParameter<decimal>>()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(param => 
            {
                var parameter = MeteoParameterFactory.Create(param.ParameterId, param.DateTime.ToLocalTime(), param.Status, param.Value);
                parameter.Info = param.Info;
                newValues.Add(parameter);
            });
```